# How to separate the data in string?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an **array of String**

```
String[] data = {"Id:1492", "Name:Antony", "School:DPS"};
```

I want to know **how to separate the data** like:

```
Id = 1492
Name = Antony
School = DPS
```

Comment: show us your attempt!

Comment: you want data set in some class or just string ?

Comment: Split() and replace()/replaceAll() my friend .. split() and replace()/replaceAll()

Comment: Actually, I'm getting json like data into the home controller, when i use toJSON/fromJSO its not working, its giving me unsupported serialization. So I'm thinking of separating in other way. Pls help

Comment: Not sure but it sounded like he wants to create variables named Id, Name and School. In that case I would have said "no variable variables in Java, my friend, no variable variables" :)

Comment: ERROR in your question: it won't compile.... use `String[] data` not `String data`!

Answer (score 0):

Using org.json library (http://www.json.org/java/)

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
```

and then you can access the ID and other data out of the `jsonObj`

Comment: I Used MetricsMaster newMetricsData = json.fromJson(metricsMasterData, MetricsMaster.class); and i got below error Throwable occurred: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:184)
 at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$StringTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:968)
 at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$StringTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:960)
 at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:51)

Answer (score 0):

Its a json string so better use a json parser. You have multiple choices for java json parsers api available for free. Few are mentioned here:

- [JSON](http://www.json.org/java/)
- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would replace `{` and `}` from the string then get array from that using:

`String values[] = data .replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",");`

Then `iterate over array` and put the key-value pairs in a `Map` by spliting array element with:

`String[] value= values[index].split(":");`

and using `value[0]` as a key and `value[1]` as a pair.

Or as another option I suggest to use some `JSON api for java`.

Here is the sample code:

```
String data ="{Id:1492,Name:Antony ,School:DPS}";
String values[] = data .replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",");
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    String value[] = values[i].split(":");
    map.put(value[0], value[1]);
}
System.out.println(map.toString());
```

Comment: The question contains an error: the example doesn't compile... OP's trying to assign an array to a String (look closely).

Comment: @ambigram_maker: Written lines are only for demonstration to give actual idea and I tried compiling line 2nd and 4th and it did compile in my environment

Comment: HOW?! How on earth did it compile? Copy the actual code snippet.

Comment: copied both the lines and pasted it in eclipse in currently open java file and it didn't give any error, just mentioned two lines

Comment: Show exactly what did u paste? Show here:

Comment: `String data ="{\"Id\":1492,\"Name\":\"Antony \",\"School\":\"DPS\"}";
     String values[] = data .replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",");
     String[] value= values[0].split(":");`

Comment: Well, OP did not put the `""`, neither the `;` :-)

Comment: But when she actually codes she will do it. :-)
either:
`String data ="{\"Id\":1492,\"Name\":\"Antony \",\"School\":\"DPS\"}";`
 Or:
    ` String data ="{Id:1492,Name:Antony ,School:DPS}";`

Comment: Fine... I've added another (easy) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] data = {"Id\", "1492\", "Name\", "Antony\", "School\", "DPS\"};

String arr[] = data.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  String keyval[] = arr[i].split(":");
  for (int j = 0; j < keyval.length; j += 2) {
    System.out.print(keyval[j].replaceAll("\\{*\"+", ""));
    System.out.print(":");
    System.out.print(keyval[j + 1].replaceAll("\"+}*", ""));
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code doesn't compile**:
You are trying to save ***various types of objects*** `(String, int)` in an `array` to a `String`!? Why? You statement should be:

```
String[] data = {"Id:1492","Name:Antony","School:DPS"};
```

instead of :

```
String data = {"Id":1492,"Name":"Antony ","School":"DPS"}
```

Now that it compiles, let's solve the problem...

---

How about this; it uses plain java:

```
...
String id;
String name;
String school;
for (String str : data) {
    int pos = str.indexOf (":"); //Find [1st] position of ':'
    String part1 = str.substring(0, pos);
    String part2 = str.substring(pos + 1);
    switch (part1) {
        case "Id":
            id = part2;
            break;
        case "Name":
            name = part2;
            break;
        case "School":
            school = part2;
            break;
    }
}
...
```

If you want to sreate a new Object from the data like a `Student` perhaps, then put this code in a method called `parse (String[] data)` in the `class Student`. The `id`, `name`, `school` should be `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Won't it be easier to use a HashMap?